# Ramanujan's Proof of Chebycheff's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, sieve-theory, chebyshev-function

**Background:** We define $$\theta(x) := \sum_{p\le x} \log p$$
where the sum is taken over primes $\le x$.

> **Chebycheff’s Theorem**: There exist positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that $$Ax < \theta(x) < Bx$$

---

The book by Cojocaru and Murty presents a proof due to Ramanujan, which is paraphrased below with inline questions.

> Observe that if $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers with $a_n \to 0$, then $$a_0 - a_1 \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n \le a_0 - a_1 + a_2$$
> *(The book uses absolute convergence of the series to prove this assertion, but later uses this assertion for a series with only finitely many terms, so we should not bother ourselves with this aspect.)*
> Following Chebycheff, we define
> $$\psi(x) := \sum_{p^a \le x} \log p$$
> where the summation is over all prime powers $p^a \le x$. We let $$T(x) := \sum_{n\le x} \psi\left(\frac x n\right)$$
> and notice that $$\sum_{n\le x} \log n = {{\sum_{n\le x} \left(\sum_{p^a \mid n} \log p\right) = \sum_{m\le x} \psi\left(\frac x m \right)}} = T(x)$$

1. Where does the second equality above come from?

> By an earlier observation (that $\sum_{n\le x} \log n = x\log x - x + O(\log x))$ we have
> $$T(x) = x\log x - x + O(\log x)$$
> so that
> $$T(x) - 2T\left(\frac x 2\right) = x \log 2 + O(\log x)$$
> On the other hand,
> $$T(x) - 2T\left(\frac x 2\right) = \sum_{n\le x} (-1)^{n-1} \psi\left(\frac x n \right)$$
> and we can apply our initial observation to deduce
> $$\psi(x) - \psi\left(\frac x 2\right) + \psi\left(\frac x 3\right) \ge x\log 2 + O(\log x) \tag{1}$$
> and
> $$\psi(x) - \psi\left(\frac x 2\right) \le x\log 2 + O(\log x) \tag{2}$$
> because $a_n = \psi(x/n)$ is a decreasing sequence of real numbers tending to
> zero (in fact, equal to zero for $n > x$). By successively replacing $x$ with $x/2^k$ in the above inequality $(2)$, we obtain
> $$\psi(x) \le 2x\log 2 + O(\log^2 x) \tag{3}$$
> This completes Ramanujan’s proof of Chebycheff's theorem.

2. I've worked out the last step, and I want to confirm the correctness of my work. From equation $(3)$, we have $\psi(x) \le 2x\log 2 + c_1 \log ^2 x$ for some $c_1 > 0$. We can find $\beta > 0$ such that $\psi(x) < \beta x$ for sufficiently large $x$, say for $x > k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$. For $1\le x\le k$, $\psi(x) \le 2k\log 2 + c_1 \log^2 k$, i.e., $\psi(x)$ is bounded. We can choose $B = \max\{\beta, 2k\log 2 + c_1 \log^2 k + 1\}$ to get $\psi(x) < Bx$ for all $x$. Lastly, we get the required upper bound using $\theta(x) \le \psi(x)$.
3. The proof in the book doesn't seem to address the lower bound at all. I suspect we must use equation $(1)$, i.e., $\psi(x) - \psi\left(\frac x 2\right) + \psi\left(\frac x 3\right) \ge x\log 2 + O(\log x)$ to derive it. An added problem in the case of the lower bound is that $\theta(x) \le \psi(x)$, and not the other way round. To find $A > 0$ such that $\theta(x) > Ax$ for all $x$, we may have to find another way to compare $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ too, i.e., consider the growth of $|\theta(x) - \psi(x)|$ with $x$. Could someone help me fill in the details for the lower bound?

Thank you!

---

Reference: *An Introduction to Sieve Methods and Their Applications* by
Alina Carmen Cojocaru and M. Ram Murty.

Comment: What is the inequality in blue? just clarify that part, please.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I notice some formulas are brighter. I have turned off blue color on my monitor :D I can't see blue well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may explain the answer to the first question:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{p^\alpha|n}=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{p^\alpha\cdot m=n}=\sum_{p^\alpha m\leq x}=\sum_{m\leq x}\sum_{p^\alpha\leq\frac{x}{m}}.$$
And for the third question, let's firstly observe:
$$T(x)-2T\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\leq\psi(x),$$
and then recall the estimate value of the left-hand side to get that $\psi(x)$ is bounded from below by $cx$ for some $c$. Finally, you want to discuss the growth of $\theta(x)-\psi(x)$ indeed. For that use
$$\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\theta\left(x^\frac{1}{n}\right)=\theta(x)+\sum_{n=2}^{\log_2x}\theta\left(x^\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\theta(x)+\sum_{n=2}^{\log_2x}\theta\left(\sqrt{x}\right)=\theta(x)+\mathcal{O}(\ln x\cdot\theta(\sqrt{x}))=$$
$$=\theta(x)+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x}\cdot\ln x),$$
where we used that $\theta(x)=0$ for $x<2$ and that $\theta(x)=\mathcal{O}(x)$ which we already know. Recall once again that $\theta(x)=\mathcal{O}(x)$ to get:
$$\psi(x)=\theta(x)+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x}\cdot\ln x)=$$
$$=\mathcal{O}(x)+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x}\cdot\ln x)=\mathcal{O}(x).$$
To show that $\theta(x)$ is bounded from below by a linear function we use the difference with $\psi(x)$ which we got earlier to find:
$$\theta(x)=\psi(x)-\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x}\cdot\ln x)=\Omega(x)+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x}\cdot\ln x)=\Omega(x).$$
For detailed description of used notations, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations). It should be clear how each step was deduced.

Comment: Could you give some more details for the third question?

Comment: @stoic-santiago I added some details. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: That error term can be improved to $O(\sqrt x)$ if you break that sum into $\theta(\sqrt x)+\sum_{n\ge3}\theta(x^{1/n})$

Comment: @TravorLZH That is right. We can use results in loops, make them improve each other.